# Add Css to a created plugin in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

Working on my first Wordpress plugin i'm stuck.

My plugin allows users to add on their pages and articles some of social media's link.

I want to add some style but it doesn't work.
I show you parts of my code.

**First the construct method**

```
    function __construct() {
    add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'menu'));
    add_filter('the_content', array($this, 'ifWrap'));
    }
```

**Where i added Css Files**

```
    function menu() {

    // First the Css for the Admin Page
    add_action("load-{$mainPageHook}", array($this, 'mainPageAssets'));
    
    // Here i tried to add a Css File for the plugin render
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'asmsl_load_plugin_css' );

    }

function asmsl_load_plugin_css() {
    $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style1', $plugin_url . 'css/styleRender.css');
}
```

**Where i verify and i call the HTML create**

```
    function ifWrap($content) {
    if(is_main_query() AND is_single() AND (
        isset(get_option("asmslp_social_choice")['fcb']) == '1'
    )) {
        return $this->createHTML($content);
    }

    return $content;
}
```

**Finally the HTML element created**

```
function createHTML($content) {
    
    $size_30 = "height: 30px;";

    $color = 'color: blue';

    if(isset(get_option("asmslp_social_choice")['fcb']) == '1') {
        $html .= '<a href="" style=" ' . $size_30 . ' "></a>';
    }
```

When i use some classes or ids from my css file it doesn't work. The only way for me to add style is inline style.

Have you got idea about using css file here ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `admin_menu` action hook. This is only executed in the backend. So, the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook will never get executed.

What you should do is move `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts'` to the constructor.

Comment: I finally found the solution yesterday. But you're right, that was the reason. Thank you :) It was an idiot error.